# ASP MVC href to a controller/view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, href

I have this:

```
<li><a href="/Users/Index)" class="elements"><span>Clients</span></a></li>
```

Which works fine. But if I am already on this page or on the controller e.g. `/Users/Details` and I click on this link it redirects me to `/Users/Index`.

How can I get the correct path in the `href` regardless of my current position on the site?

Comment: Go Thru This .. : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/583469/MVC-Different-Redirection-Techniques-Razor

Answer (score 197, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can accomplish this. You can do the following:

```
<li>
     @Html.ActionLink("Clients", "Index", "User", new { @class = "elements" }, null)
</li>
```

or this:

```
<li>
     <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Users")" class="elements">
          <span>Clients</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

Lately I do the following:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", null, new { area = string.Empty, controller = "User" }, Request.Url.Scheme)">
     <span>Clients</span>
</a>
```

The result would have `http://localhost/10000` (or with whatever port you are using) to be appended to the URL structure like:

```
http://localhost:10000/Users
```

Answer (score 21):

how about

```
<li>
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Users")" class="elements"><span>Clients</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try the following:

```html
<a asp-controller="Users" asp-action="Index"></a>
```

This is part of the new [Anchor Tag Helper system for Razor pages that was introduced in ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-1.0).

Comment: Its not valid for ASP.NET. Maybe valid for old ASP pages.

Comment: Only valid for ASP.NET 5 i.e MVC 6

Answer (score 6):

You can modify with the following

```
<li><a href="./Index" class="elements"><span>Clients</span></a></li>
```

The extra dot means you are in the same controller. If you want change the controller to a different controller then you can write this

```
<li><a href="../newController/Index" class="elements"><span>Clients</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here '~' refers to the root directory ,where Home is controller and Download_Excel_File is actionmethod

```
 <a href="~/Home/Download_Excel_File" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this very simplified form:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Come back to Home", "Index", "Home")
```

Where : 
`Come back to Home` is the text that will appear on the page 
`Index` is the view name 
`Home`is the controller name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one modal for Create and Update You can also do this

**C#**

```
onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdate","Request",null,Context.Request.Scheme)','Create Request')"


onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdate","Request",new{id = item.id },Context.Request.Scheme)','Edit Request')"
```

**JS**

```
showInPopup = (url, title) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (res) {
            $("#form-modal .modal-body").html(res);
            $("#form-modal .modal-title").html(title);
            $("#form-modal").modal('show');
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If using ASP.NET Core, you can adjust the accepted answer to:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", null, new { area = string.Empty, controller = "User" }, @Context.Request.Scheme)">
     <span>Clients</span>
</a>
```

replacing `@Request.Url.Scheme`
with `@Context.Request.Scheme`